# VB.NET BindingSource Filter two column conversion not valid

Tags: database, vb.net, filter, long-integer, bindingsource

I need to filter my Table2 with ID number and with year >=2010.

This is my code for filter:

```
Me.Table2BindingSource.Filter = "osobljeID ='" & OsobljeIDTextBox.Text & "'" And "Godina >=" & txtGodP.Text
```

When I start app and click on button with this code I got:

> Conversion from string "osobljeID ='1'" to type 'Long' is not valid.

When I use only one column to filter all is working but I need two.

(e.g [Me.Table2BindingSource.Filter = "osobljeID ='" & OsobljeIDTextBox.Text & "'"])
 but with "And" it give err.

Comment: You have data conversion and string concat issues.   Your AND is not in the quotes so it is performing an operation on 2 strings which is illegal.  You should also turn on `Option Strict` it will point this out in the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Me.Table2BindingSource.Filter = "osobljeID = '" & OsobljeIDTextBox.Text & "' AND Godina >= " & txtGodP.Text
```

The operator AND should be part of the filter string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me and my time. Thanks again.